# Cant concatenate videos with python using moviepy

Tags: python, moviepy, windowserror

this is the code

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip, concatenate_videoclips
clip1 = VideoFileClip ("intro.mp4",audio=True)
clip2 = VideoFileClip ("myvideo2.mp4").subclip(50,60)
clip3 = VideoFileClip("myvideo3.mp4")
final_clip = concatenate_videoclips([clip1,clip2,clip3])
final_clip.write_videofile("my_concatenation.mp4")
```

where as i am getting an error like this when i run

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\INTEL\Desktop\Youtube bot\add3.py", line 2, in <module>
    clip1 = VideoFileClip ("intro.mp4",audio=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\VideoFileClip.py", line 57, in __init__
    reader = FFMPEG_VideoReader(filename, pix_fmt=pix_fmt)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py", line 32, in __init__
    infos = ffmpeg_parse_infos(filename, print_infos, check_duration)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\moviepy\video\io\ffmpeg_reader.py", line 241, in ffmpeg_parse_infos
    proc.terminate()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 1002, in terminate
    _subprocess.TerminateProcess(self._handle, 1)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied
>>>
```

please help me !

Comment: Do you have read permissions in the directory containing the video files?

Comment: yeah it have all  permissions

Comment: this script was an example script from moviepy documentation User Guide     [Moviepy Link](http://zulko.github.io/moviepy/getting_started/compositing.html)

Comment: Does it do this for all videos or just this one?